# passing parameter from vbscript to oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, vbscript

Dim strConnection, conn, rs, strSQL, objCommand, param
    strConnection = "Driver={Oracle ODBC Driver};Data Source=DSNNAME;User
    Id=Username;Password=password;"
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open strConnection

```
Dim cmdInsert As ADODB.Command
Set cmdInsert = New ADODB.Command
cmdInsert.ActiveConnection = conn
cmdInsert.CommandText = "sp_ins_test"
cmdInsert.CommandType = 4
cmdInsert.Parameters.Refresh

Set param = cmdInsert.Parameters
param.Append cmdInsert.CreateParameter("v_BG_EI_DEFECT_TYPE", 200, 1, 100, "abc")
param.Append cmdInsert.CreateParameter("v_BG_EI_APP_ID", 3, 1, 8, 1) 
param.Append cmdInsert.CreateParameter("v_BG_DETECTION_DATE", 133, 1, 100, 8/6/2010)
```

cmdInsert.Execute

It is throwing error as Character to number conversion error but i am passing int the 
   code is 3 for integer(but the datatype is number in database) and also passing date

Please tell me how to pass parameters to date and number datatype in oracle..

Answer (score 1):

I can see at least these problems:

- If the script really shall be VBScript, then `As ADODB.Command` and `New ADODB.Command` are illegal; these are valid in VB only. Use `CreateObject` instead.
- `8/6/2010` is not a valid date literal, it is an integer expression evaluating to a very small value (almost 0); use `#8/6/2010#` instead.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in empty `strings` into your parameters.